# Javascript: Getting the Id of selected options

Tags: javascript

To get the value of the selected option

```
$("#id_CITY").change(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    a = el.val()
)};
```

But how do i get the id?

Comment: Note this is about getting the **`id`** of the option, not the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you don't want `id`s on `option` elements because there's little point.

However, if you have some reason for doing it, you can get the `id` of the selected option by finding the `option:selected` and reading its `id`:

```
$("#id_CITY").change(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var a = el.val(); // <== Note `var`
    var selectedId = el.find("option:selected").attr("id");
}); // <== Note you had a typo here; this is fixed
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$("#id_CITY").change(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var value = el.val();
    var selectedId = el.find("option:selected").attr("id");
    $("<p>").text(
      "value = '" + value + "', id = '" + selectedId + "'"
    ).appendTo(document.body);
});
```

```html
<select id="id_CITY">
  <option id="first" value="1st">First</option>
  <option id="second" value="2nd">Second</option>
  <option id="third" value="3rd">Third</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: indeed, there's usually little point in having an `id` attribute on an `<option>` element.

Comment: instead of jQuery functions, there's `this.selectedOptions[0].id` (if it's not a multi-select)

Comment: I'm trying to build my own dynamic dropdown, thanks.